# I can't apply Azure for Student with Github Education Student Benefits

Tags: azure, github

I have been allowed to use Github Education Student Benefits
but I can't apply Azure for Student authentication From the link which set in benefits list webpage

[picture the github account has been allowed for education benefits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrDGh.png)

[picture:link of benefits list webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IYLE.png)

[picture:error returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uytQT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reach out to the billing support:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/